# A problem on analysis specifically on functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

Let $f(x)$ be a function from reals to reals obeying the following: $f(x)$ is continuous, $f(0)=1$, and $f(m+n+1)=f(m)+f(n)$. Show that $f(x) =1 +x$ for all real numbers $x$.

I am a bit confused on how to start with the sum as I am new to analysis. Assuming $f(x)=1+x$. I can indeed show that it satisfies properties $f(m+n+1) =f(m) + f(n)$, (where m and n are reals) by checking it for RHS and LHS alternatively but can't prove it using the condition itself

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add the upvote.

Comment: Please take a look at [Cauchy functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation). Can you reduce your problem to that?

Comment: When  you  type  the  question ,  take  a  look  at  the  "MathJaX Help"  link  on  the  right  bottom  corner .  That  will  help  you  type  the  mathematical  symbols.

Comment: Are $m$ and $n$ natural or integer numbers, or reals?

Answer (score 1):

At first, we have the following relation
$$f(x+y+1)=f(x)+f(y);$$
or
$$f(x+y)=f(x+(y-1)+1)=f(x)+f(y-1);\ \ \ \ \ (*)$$
for all $x, y\in \mathbb{R}$. Now define the funtion $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $g(x):=f(x)-1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Now, by replacing $x:=0$ in relation $(*)$ , we get $f(y)=f(0)+f(y-1)=f(y-1)+1$ we have 
$$g(x+y)=f(x+y)-1=f(x)+f(y-1)-1=(f(x)-1)+((f(y-1)+1)-1)=(f(x)-1)+(f(y)-1)=g(x)+g(y)$$
for all $x, y\in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore the function $g$ satisfies the Cauchy functional equation (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) and since the function $g$  is continuous and $g(0)=0$, implies that $g(x)=x$ and so $f(x)=x+1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Note that in question, if suppose that the relation $$f(x+y+1)=f(x)+f(y);$$ is true only for rationals, then the solution is same as above, but if the functional equation is true only for integers, then the functions $f(x):=x+1+\sin(2\pi x)$ and  $f(x):=x+1+\cos((\pi/2)+2x\pi)$ satisfy in the given functional equation.